# What is the mathematical operation used by the python hash() function?

Tags: hash

```
print(hash('hello world'))
```

result :

```
6266945022561323786
```

What is the mathematical used by the python hash() function ?

Comment: Run it again and see what value you get. That should tell you something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python documentation makes no guarantee about the particular algorithm that is used by `hash()` (or more precisely, `object.__hash__(self)`).

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel#object.__hash__) only says this:

> ## `object.__hash__(self)`
>
> Called by built-in function `hash()` and for operations on members of hashed collections including `set`, `frozenset`, and `dict`. The `__hash__()` method should return an integer. The only required property is that objects which compare equal have the same hash value; it is advised to mix together the hash values of the components of the object that also play a part in comparison of objects by packing them into a tuple and hashing the tuple. Example:
>
> ```python
> def __hash__(self):
>     return hash((self.name, self.nick, self.color))
> ```

The only thing that is guaranteed is this: "The only required property is that objects which compare equal have the same hash value".

There are a couple of *desirable* properties related to security, safety, and performance, but they are not *required*.

Every object can implement its own `__hash__()` however it wants, as long as it satisfies the property that two equal objects have the same hash value. And, in fact, many objects *do* provide their own implementations.

Even for built-in core objects such as `str`ings, different implementations (and even different versions of different implementations) use different algorithms. CPython even uses a different seed value every time you run it (again, for security reasons).

So, the answer is: you can't know what the algorithm is. All you know is that if `a.__eq__(b)` is `True`, then `a.__hash__().__eq__(b.__hash__())` is also `True`.

Most importantly, there is *no* guarantee that `a.__hash__().__eq__(b.__hash__())` being `True` implies `a` and `b` are equal, nor does `a.__eq__(b)` being `False` imply that `a.__hash__().__eq__(b.__hash__())` is `False`.